# Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f: X \to Y$ a quotient map. Show that $X$ is connected if $Y$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ are connected.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f: X \to Y$ a quotient map. Show that $X$ is connected if $Y$ and $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ are connected for all $y \in Y$.

I first tried the contradiction approach and assumed that $X$ isn't connected. Then $X= A \cup B$ for $A,B$ open and $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Now as $f$ is a quotient map we have that $A=f^{-1}(U)$ and $B=f^{-1}(V)$ for some $U,V$ open in $Y$. I couldn't get a contradiction from here to the connectedness for $Y$ or the fibers.

---

Now I tried the direct approach and noted that since $X$ is surjective for every $y \in Y$ there exists $x \in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. Thus $X= \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(\{y\})$. If I just now could show that $\bigcap_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is non-empty I would be done, but I didn't find a way to do this.

What would be the correct way to approach the problem?

Comment: First approach. Hint: Any fibre must be completely in $A$ or completely in $B$.

Comment: As $X = A \cup B = \bigcup_{y \in Y} f^{-1}(\{y\})$?

Comment: I think I also have that $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B) = Y$ so if I can show that $f(A) \cap f(B)= \emptyset$, then I get a contradiction of $Y$'s connectedness. But I only have that $f(A \cap B) \subseteq f(A) \cap f(B)$ as $f$ isn't injective.

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $X$ is not connected and is a union of two disjoint open sets $A$ and $B$, as you started.

For any $y\in Y$ we can write the fiber of $y$ as $f^{-1}(y)=(f^{-1}(y)\cap A)\cup(f^{-1}(y)\cap B), $ as a union of two disjoint open sets. Since $f^{-1}(y)$ is connected, one of these open sets must be empty, that is, for any $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}(y)\subset A$ or $f^{-1}(y)\subset B$.

Let $C=\{y\in Y|f^{-1}(y)\subset A\}$ and $D=\{y\in Y|f^{-1}(y)\subset B\}$. It is clear that $C\cap D=\emptyset$. Then also, $f^{-1}(C)=A$ and $f^{-1}(D)=B$. Hence, $C$ and $D$ are open, since $f$ is quotient map. Also, $C\cup B=Y$. We reached to a contradiction, since $Y$ is connected.